kotlin flows, when I use collect(). The function reaches there, it does not execute logs that it has below
suspend fun getInvoiceLines(invoiceLines: Flow<List<InvoiceLine>>): List<InvoiceLine> {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val lines = mutableListOf<InvoiceLine>()
        invoiceLines.onEach { list -> lines.addAll(list) }.collect()
        lines
    }
}

What this function does is return a list, to be able to iterate over it in another function. But it has a problem, if I remove the .collect it returns empty, but if I put the .collect it is not empty but it does not go to the return of the lines
I tried to convert that flow into a list using the .toList flatten, I tried to return with the collect, I tried to use a try with a finally to return the lines but none of that worked

have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?
also, have tried running your method without the suspend keyword?
kotlin has a helpful method called also that you can insert between steps of a flow. it helps you see what's returned by the previous step.
good luck !

You shouldn't even do this in the first place. Usually you just want to collect a flow at the latest possible moment (when you have a UI, it will be collected there). Everything before that should just transform the flow. Most likely you will be able to refactor your code to do all of this only in transformation functions. How this would exactly look depends on the context where this function is called and what you do with the return value.

This is an expected behavior. Collecting a flow waits until it is fully collected. If it is an infinite flow (common case), you never finish collecting. Do you maybe need to wait for the first list that is emitted? In that case just do invoiceLines.first(). If this is not the case, then how many lists do you need to collect and what determines that you need to stop collecting?

What is the source of the flow? If this is the Room database or something similar, then please be aware by returning a flow from it we request to observe the data for changes and do this forever. If you only need to get the current data from the DB, then don't return a flow, but just a regular list (and make the function suspend). Also, you shouldn't switch to Dispatchers.IO in your case as you don't run any blocking code.

Hi, I tried answering some of your questions. I tried removing the suspend keyword in the function, I also tried removing the dispatchers.IO in various ways, as well as using first and also, but none of these worked because the collect never finishes. Basically, using Room Database

I return a Flow<List>, and what I need is to iterate over the data of that Flow to do certain things in another function. I tried saving the data in another list where I can iterate without using a collect, but having to put the collect at the end of each function, I haven't found a way to be able to execute all of this. Mainly because after iterating over the list, other things need to be done.
